# trigram index for integer field

Tags: postgresql, index

I am trying to optimize query with the clause:

```
WHERE LOWER(CAST(\"my_table\".\"id\" as TEXT) LIKE '%456%'
```

I decided to create a trigram index for it.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON my_table USING gin (id gin_trgm_ops);
```

But looks like I can't do it for an integer type:

```
ERROR:  operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not accept data type bigint
```

Is it possible? Probably some typecast required during index creation...

Comment: LIKE isn't intended for numbers. This really looks like a very strange query.

Comment: this is the query for search ids by its substring, ids are integers

Comment: I understand what you are doing. But I don't understand why someone would want to search for "substrings" of a number. I can't picture the use case. Btw: `LOWER(CAST(\"my_table\".\"id\" as TEXT)` can be simplified to `my_table.id::text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to create the trigram index on the *complete* expression left of the `LIKE` operator.

The `lower` is unnecessary, and you should omit it.